# Using Angular Bootstrap directive "uib-popover" with dynamically generated SVG content

Tags: angularjs, svg, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a case where I am dynamically generating SVG. This is in various forms but, for example, I do things like this;

```
<rect uib-popover=\"I will show data!\" popover-append-to-body=\"true\" popover-placement=\"bottom\" popover-trigger=\"mouseenter\" id=\"component-#{SecureRandom.uuid}\" x=\"#{pos_x + (component_width / 2)}\" y=\"#{MID_LINE - (component_height / 2)}\" width=\"#{component_width}\" height=\"#{component_height}\" style=\"stroke-width:0.5; stroke:rgb(0,0,0)\" />
```

The SVG document is sent back to the browser and dynamically injected into a DIV (via an Angular controller).

The problem is that the popover will not appear. It seems as if the page is not "re-scanned" when the content is injected (and therefore the `uib-popover` is never seen).

I have done some tests to confirm this. For example, a direct placement of SVG in the page works;

```
<svg>
  <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="10" uib-popover="Hello world" popover-title="Title!" popover-append-to-body="true" popover-placement="right" popover-trigger="mouseenter"/>
</svg>
```

And the popover is displayed.

Doing it this way though, does not work;

```
<div ng-bind-html="svg"></div>
```

Where the `svg` variable is within the controller and is set by;

```
$scope.svg = $sce.trustAsHtml('<svg><circle cx="30" cy="30" r="10" uib-popover="Hello world" popover-title="Title!" popover-append-to-body="true" popover-placement="right" popover-trigger="mouseenter"/></svg>')
```

In this case the popover does *not* appear.

So what am I missing? Is there any method by which I can inject SVG dynamically into a page and have the Angular/Bootstrap directives work? Perhaps some way to tell the directives to re-bind?

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: Angular doesn't compile the html that you've injected so any directives inside the injected code won't run. To achieve what you're trying to do you'll have to compile the injected code using angular's $compile service or by transclusion (which automatically runs the angular compiler). How are you retrieving your SVG?